# How can I send special characters as value in a ajax and decoded on php side?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the code ,

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_ajax.php",         
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ({ description : description.val(), project_id : project_id.val()}), 
        success: ( $(".succes_update_description").append("Update Successfull") )
        });
```

php side I have

```
<?php mysqli_query($conn, "update someDB.someTable set description='".$_POST['description']."' where id='".$_POST['project_id']."'"); ?>
```

after that when I try to

so , when description.val() contains characters like ' or " or \ , I can't update the string in mysql. how can I resolve that?

Comment: its because you are not escaping your string properly which will lead to an SQL injection.  look into using prepared statements and pdo an update your database insert appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't trust your user, never! Escape or cast all the values you're using in your queries. Your code should look something like this:

```
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$id = (int)$_POST['project_id'];

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE someDB.`someTable` SET `description`='".description."' WHERE `id`='".$id."'");
```

Comment: ye, it works, the right syntax was
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);

where $conn is the result of connection to mysql